# How can I instruct less to ignore math for certain styles?

Tags: less

I'm using the new `calc` function in CSS to get the width for an object, as in:

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Unfortunately, since this is in a LESS file, LESS is "helpfully" pre-converting this to 60% during compile time.

I want less to ignore math when it's in a `calc` function since I need the *browser* to do this calculation, not less.

Is there anyway I can make LESS ignore this calculation so I can pass it straight to the browser?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use it through an escaped string:

```
width: ~"calc(100% - 40px)";
```

Which outputs purely as CSS:

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Instead of precalculating `width: calc(60%)` (as you are experiencing).

NOTE: **LESS 1.4+ does not need this escaped string** if the **strict-math** mode is set, as all "math" then requires its own parenthesis to trigger. So LESS 1.4+ in that mode could be used *as you originally had it*, and if you *wanted* it to do the math, it would need extra parentheses and a `unit()` function like so: `width: calc((100% - unit(40px)));`.